# Rails Composite Keys - Setting up models and assocs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, database-design, composite-primary-key

I'm using Rails Composite Keys for the first time and even though I've read the docs, I'm still unsure how to set up the models correctly.

An Activity can be Scheduled by a Provider. I want a join table that tracks `activity_id` and `provider_id` as a unique composite key so that I can associate it with something else (prices). The composite needs to be generated upon the creation of a new schedule. The provider does not necessarily own the activity themselves directly.

I've got this for my composite key as it's own model. Is this right?

```
class ScheduledActivity < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_keys = :provider_id, :activity_id
  belongs_to :activity
  belongs_to :provider
  has_many :schedules, :foreign_key => [:provider_id, :activity_id]
  has_many :prices, :foreign_key => [:provider_id, :activity_id]
end
```

This for the db migration:

```
class CreateJoinTableScheduledActivities < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_join_table :providers, :activities, table_name: :scheduled_activities do |t|
      t.index [:provider_id, :activity_id]
    end
  end
end
```

How do I then get new entries on the join table as Schedules are created? Do I put only `belongs_to :scheduled_activity` on this model - i.e. no provider and activity ids on the Schedule table, and do I write a separate hook in order to create the new composite keys?

(Also - is this the correct use case for composite keys in the first place?!)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm not sure if this fully answers your question but if you have a composite unique key you can do something like the following.

In your migration:

```
add_index :scheduled_activities, [:provider_id, :activity_id], unique: true
```

In your join model:

```
belongs_to :activity
belongs_to :provider

validates :activity, presence: true, uniqueness: { scope: :provider }
```

Given that this is more than a simple join table maybe you should consider using id's to identify each ScheduledActivity, then you can simply add that reference to your Schedule model/table (Schedule `belongs_to :schedule_activity` - schedules table will have a reference to schedule_activity with attribute `schedule_activity_id`, instead of using a composite key). It would make things much simpler and efficient.